# Resizing UIImageView based on UITableViewCell content height using autolayout constraints

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard, autolayout

I have a `UITableViewCell` xib with below view:
[image]

As shown it has below components:

1. `UILabel` - dateLabel
2. `UILabel` - addressLabel
3. `UILabel` - criteriaLabel
4. `UIImageView` - separatorImageView

Since I want to increase the height of cell based on contents in the labels, I added below constraints to each:

[image]

So dateLabel constraints are:

[image]

addressLabel constraints are:

[image]

criteriaLabel constraints are:

[image]

Without adding constraints for `separatorImageView`, cells appear like this:

[image]

ie. cells are resizing based on content which is perfect :)

Now problem is - if I add below constraints to `separatorImageView`:

[image]

Cells start appearing like this:

[image]

Please suggest which constraints shall I add to `separatorImageView` so that it resizes as per the height of cell without affecting proper resizing of cell.

Comment: What content mode are you using for the UIImageView? Make sure it is set to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Comment: I checked in attribute inspector, it is AspectFit, also point to note over here is that once I add autolayout constraints to it, it affects behaviour of other constraints as well, which can be observed in last image

Comment: Try UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill. If it still looks that way set its background color nonwhite and look what is the real image frame.

Comment: sure I will try that, but still I will face the incorrect cell height problem, which I get on applying autolayout constraints to image view, please refer last image added by me for same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the best answer but for special cases I do this:

1. create a UIView named *resizingVIEW*, pin it to top, bottom, trailing, leading of super view (contentView)
2. remove *separatorImageView* **Bottom Space Constraint**
3. ctrl+click from separatorImageView to *resizingVIEW*, select equal height

(NOTE set resizingVIEW background color to clear color/ or hide it)